# Thin gray lines as links plotting sankeyNetwork in R

Tags: r, plot, sankey-diagram

Disclaimer: I'm an R newbie, so I may be overlooking something really obvious here...

I am currently working on a sankeyNetwork diagram using R, and I am facing a problem that almost seems to be a bug, but I'm completely clueless...
I've googled extensively, and haven't been able to find anybody else reporting the same...

The problem is that in my code I currently have 7 nodes, and 5 links. When I plot the diagram, everything works fine:
[Plot 1, everything working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nExnQ.png)

This is the code for Plot 1:

```
library(networkD3)

# List of nodes (portfolios & targets)
nodes = data.frame("trialnodes" =
                       c("portfolio1", # 0
                         "portfolio2", # 1
                         "portfolio3", # 2
                         "portfolio4", # 3
                         "target1", # 4
                         "target2", # 5
                         "target3" # 6
                       ))

# List of links
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
    0,4,2,
    1,6,1,
    2,3,1,
    2,6,1,
    3,5,1),
    byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

# Column names of data frame
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

# check
links

# Sankey Diagram
# Colour scale
colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);")

# Diagram
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "trialnodes",
              fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 10, nodePadding = 140, iterations = 0,
              colourScale = colourScale)
```

however, as soon as I add one more node, and 1 more link, the plot's format becomes completely broken, showing the links between nodes as simple gray thin lines (not representing the Value). The nodeWidth and nodePadding specifications also get ignored :(
[Plot 2, links as thin gray lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crnuW.png)

This is the code for Plot 2:

```
library(networkD3)
# List of nodes (portfolios & targets)
nodes = data.frame("trialnodes" =
                       c("portfolio1", # 0
                         "portfolio2", # 1
                         "portfolio3", # 2
                         "portfolio4", # 3
                         "target1", # 4
                         "target2", # 5
                         "target3", # 6
                         "target4" # 7
                       ))

# List of links
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
    0,4,2,
    0,7,1,
    1,6,1,
    2,3,1,
    2,6,1,
    3,5,1),
    byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

# Column names of data frame
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

# check
links

# Sankey Diagram
# Colour scale
colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);")

# Diagram
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "trialnodes",
              fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 10, nodePadding = 140, iterations = 0,
              colourScale = colourScale)
```

Can anybody spot what's going on? I hope someone can help... I'm desperate D: Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. On my env, your 2nd code runs and makes a graph like Plot 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! I get the same results as @cuttlefish44. Can you try restarting your R session ?

Comment: :-/ really? any ideas of what exactly I should be trying to fix?
I'm running R 3.6.2, RStudio 1.2.5019, in macOS Mojave 10.14.6... in case it's relevant

Comment: @RoB Unfortunately restarting isn't fixing the problem :( I actually reinstalled the whole program while trying to fix it on my own, with no success...

Comment: @Montse This is strange... You consistently get the correct plot with the first code ?

Comment: @RoB yes! the first code works fine consistently. Playing around with the code a little bit more, I was able to add one more node, and it plotted correctly, however, as soon as I modified something in the links (I didn't even add an extra one, just changed the "connections"), it broke :( I haven't been able to spot a pattern... but the first code always works well...

Comment: Update: I ran the code that was not working on a different computer and it worked, but then I changed some things there (added new nodes), and when I ran it the plot was with this thin gray lines AGAIN!!!

@RoB Could you maybe try adding nodes to either of those codes, and re-plotting it to see if the same happens to you, please?

Comment: If you change the nodes, you’ll have to change the links accordingly, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Either reduce your `nodePadding` value to something reasonable, or make the viewer/browser-window size large enough to show the max number of nodes you have in a column * 140 pixels (plus some for the actual node) and then refresh (in your second example that comes out to ~600px).

```r
library(networkD3)
# List of nodes (portfolios & targets)
nodes = data.frame("trialnodes" =
                     c("portfolio1", # 0
                       "portfolio2", # 1
                       "portfolio3", # 2
                       "portfolio4", # 3
                       "target1", # 4
                       "target2", # 5
                       "target3", # 6
                       "target4" # 7
                     ))

# List of links
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  0,4,2,
  0,7,1,
  1,6,1,
  2,3,1,
  2,6,1,
  3,5,1),
  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

# Column names of data frame
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

# check
links

# Sankey Diagram
# Colour scale
colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);")

# Diagram
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "trialnodes",
              fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 10, nodePadding = 14, iterations = 0,
              colourScale = colourScale)
```

[image]