# Plotting a Sankey Diagram using R

Tags: r, plot, sankey-diagram

Due to a mysterious problem discussed [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368322/thin-gray-lines-as-links-plotting-sankeynetwork-in-r?noredirect=1#comment104934184_59368322), I currently can't plot a Sankey Diagram using R.

Since some reported being unable to replicate my problem on their R environment, and at this point I'm willing to do anything for my diagram, it occurred to me, maybe somebody could help me plotting the actual code I need, and sending me the image...

So, this is the code:

```
library(networkD3)

#List of nodes (portfolios & targets)
nodes = data.frame("finalnodes" =
                     c("portfolio1", #0
                       "portfolio2", #1
                       "portfolio3", #2
                       "portfolio4", #3
                       "target1", #4
                       "target2", #5
                       "target3", #6
                       "target4", #7
                       "target5", #8
                       "target6", #9
                       "target7", #10
                       "target8" #11
                     ))

#List of links
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  0,4,1,
  2,10,1,
  2,6,1,
  3,4,1,
  3,5,1,
  3,7,1,
  3,8,1,
  3,9,1,
  3,11,1),
  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

#Column names of data frame
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")

#check
links

#Sankey Diagram
#Colour scale
colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);")

#Diagram
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "finalnodes",
              fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 10, nodePadding = 140, iterations = 0,
              colourScale = colourScale)
```

Needless to say, when I plot it, the format is all messed up.

The plot I get:

[image: img]

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is intended as a community learning resource, so folks likely aren't going to just send you a file of your chart privately—that would defeat the aims of this being a more permanent resource. That said, what are you saying is the problem? Just the label positioning, or something else?

Comment: Yeah, I genuinely want to figure out what's wrong and the root of why I am not being able to plot this properly :( :( :(

The whole explanation of the problem I'm facing is outlined on the thread linked at the top of my post. Here's the link again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368322/thin-gray-lines-as-links-plotting-sankeynetwork-in-r?noredirect=1#comment104934184_59368322

hope you can help! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thin gray lines as links plotting sankeyNetwork in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368322/thin-gray-lines-as-links-plotting-sankeynetwork-in-r)